# Generate custom alpha numeric sequence

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to generate custom alpha numeric sequence. 
The sequence would be like this :

AA0...AA9 AB0...AB9 AC0...AC9..and so on..

In short, there are 3 places to fill..

```
On the first place, the values can go from A to Z.
  On the second place, the values can go from A to Z.
    On the last place, the value can go from 0 to 9.
```

Code :

```
  s= list('AA0')
  for i in range(26):
    for j in range(26):
        for k in range(10):
            if k<10:
                print(s[0]+s[1]+str(k))
        s[1]= chr(ord(s[1])+1)
    s[0]= chr(ord(s[0])+1)
```

I was able to generate sequence till AZ9 and then I am getting below sequence..
it should be BA0...BZ9..

```
B[0
B[1
B[2
B[3
B[4
B[5
B[6
B[7
B[8
B[9
B\0
B\1
B\2
B\3
B\4
B\5
B\6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a way to do just that:

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_uppercase, digits

for a, b, d in product(ascii_uppercase, ascii_uppercase, digits):
    print(f'{a}{b}{d}')
```

[`string.ascii_uppercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html?highlight=ascii_uppercase#string.ascii_uppercase) is just `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`; [`string.digits`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html?highlight=ascii_uppercase#string.digits) is `'0123456789'` and [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20product#itertools.product) then iterates over all combinations.

instead of `digits` you could use `range(10)` just as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20product#itertools.product):

```
>>> letters = [chr(x) for x in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1)]
>>> letters
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
>>> combinations = ["".join(map(str, x)) for x in itertools.product(letters, letters, range(10))]
>>> combinations
['AA0', 'AA1', 'AA2', 'AA3', 'AA4', 'AA5', 'AA6', 'AA7', 'AA8', 'AA9', 'AB0', 'AB1', 'AB2', 'AB3', 'AB4', 'AB5', 'AB6', 'AB7', 'AB8', 'AB9', 'AC0', 'AC1', 'AC2', 'AC3', 'AC4', 'AC5', 'AC6', 'AC7', 'AC8', 'AC9', 'AD0', 'AD1', 'AD2', 'AD3', 'AD4', 'AD5', 'AD6', 'AD7', 'AD8', 'AD9', 'AE0', 'AE1', 'AE2', 'AE3', 'AE4', 'AE5', 'AE6', 'AE7', 'AE8', 'AE9', 'AF0', 'AF1', 'AF2', 'AF3', 'AF4', 'AF5', 'AF6', 'AF7', 'AF8', 'AF9', 'AG0', 'AG1', 'AG2', 'AG3', 'AG4', 'AG5', 'AG6', 'AG7', 'AG8', 'AG9', 'AH0', 'AH1', 'AH2', 'AH3', 'AH4', 'AH5', 'AH6', 'AH7', 'AH8', 'AH9', 'AI0', 'AI1', 'AI2', 'AI3', 'AI4', 'AI5', 'AI6', 'AI7', 'AI8', 'AI9', 'AJ0', 'AJ1', 'AJ2', 'AJ3', 'AJ4', 'AJ5', 'AJ6', 'AJ7', 'AJ8', 'AJ9', 'AK0'...]
```